# Join two tables by row

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with same column I need to merge that two table like below

```
Table1

id   name

1   test1
4   test7
5   test9
6   test3


Table2    

id   name 

2   test2
3   test5
6   test3

Result
id   name

1   test1 
2   test2
3   test5
4   test7
5   test9
6   test3
```

So I need to join/merge the two tables by id and you can see id 6 present in both table I need to override table 2 value and give above result. Kindly help me to solve the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id,name from table1 
union
select id,name from table2 ;
```

other way

```
select * from (
select id,name from table1 
union
select id,name from table2)temp order by temp.id ;
```

This will arrange records id wise

UNION will eliminate duplicate record , In your case it's id 6

Answer (score 0):

When you want sorting then must be to create inner query like this

```
select * from 
(
 select id,name from table1 t1
 union      
 select id,name from table2 t2
)a order by a.id ;
```